# How to disable or override the vscode default shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-extensions

I want to develop a vscode shortcut extension,but how can I disable or override the vscode default shortcuts in my extension code?
For example, I want to set <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to format document, but it always prompts me to press the second key because of default shortcut setting.

Comment: having the same problem with some other key combination. until a solution is found try binding the command to `ctrl`+`k` `ctrl`+`k`